# How to play a video from gallery in Android?

Tags: java, android, video, android-studio, gallery

I am trying to play a video from the gallery, but i can only reach the gallery.
I have a button and when i press it i am redirected to the gallery. I can see that there are videos, but when i press the video the application crashes.

This is the "On activity result".

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO ) {
        Uri mVideoURI  = data.getData();
        video_player_view.setMediaController(media_Controller);

        video_player_view.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);

        video_player_view.requestFocus();
        video_player_view.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                video_player_view.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is "On Create"

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn_camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    Button btn_arhiva = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_arhiva);

    video_player_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_player_view);
    media_Controller = new MediaController(this);
    media_Controller.setAnchorView(video_player_view);

    btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    btn_arhiva.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*,video/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });
```

The Exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=199, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/39 }} to activity {licenta.licenta/licenta.licenta.MainActivity}:

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setMediaController(android.widget.MediaController)' on a null object reference`
```

I searched online and tutorials are made using a video from "Raw" directory. But i want it dynamically. If i record a video now, i want to be able to play it through the app.

Thank you!

Comment: have you set permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466987/how-to-pick-a-video-file-from-gallery-sdcard-and-play-it-in-app-view

Comment: I've set the permission. And i saw that question but i didn't understand the response. I'll try copy-paste it and i will comeback with an answer.

Comment: ok try if still not working than ask me for help.

Comment: I tried that code. But i still don't understand it. I copy-paste it and i resolved all the errors, i made another intent, i put a list view there and it crashed as soon as i launched the app. Only if you can tell me how to play that video.

Comment: please add your stacktrace

Comment: @DanielGrosu - Please post your log cat. what exception you got.

Comment: A null pointer.  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=199, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/39 }} to activity {licenta.licenta/licenta.licenta.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setMediaController(android.widget.MediaController)' on a null object reference

Comment: where is your `SELECT_PHOTO` declared?

Comment: I´d check the `requestcode` wether the picking was succesfully

Comment: @SebastianWalla the requestCode is 199. I declared it. But it comes 1. 
  `private static int SELECT_PHOTO = 199; `
I declared it globally

Comment: Sorry I meant the resultCode...

Comment: The result code, is 1.